# Reply post comment using Nested Comment from Ancestry gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

Im creating nested comment in my post using [ancestry gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ancestry).

And i use Rails 5.

> Here's my codes :

**Post model**

```
has_many :comments
```

**Comment model**

```
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :post
```

**I render all comments inside views/posts/show**

```
<%= render 'comment' %>
```

**Inside views/comments/_comments**

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_post_comment_path(:parent_id => comment, :post_id => @post.id) %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller**

```
  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  end
```

**comment form**

```
<%= simple_form_for new_post_comment_path(@post,@comment)  do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit "Leave Comment", class: 'btn btn-main btn-block'  %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

**rake routes**

```
           post_comments GET      /:post_id/comments(.:format)            comments#index
                         POST     /:post_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
        new_post_comment GET      /:post_id/comments/new(.:format)        comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET      /:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)   comments#edit
            post_comment GET      /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#show
                         PATCH    /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                         PUT      /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                         DELETE   /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#destroy
```

In this URL `http://localhost:3000/post_id/comments/new?parent_id=10`
, i clicked "Reply Comment", it rendered new comment form.
But if i click submit button, i got this error

> No route matches [POST] "/post_id/comments/new"

Please someone help me to solve it. Thank You

Comment: You are missing a route, there is no `POST /:post_id/comments/new(.:format)        comments#new` when you run `rake routes`. Can you post the `routes.rb`

Comment: here's my routes : resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end

Answer (score 0):

Forget my comment. I mixed something up.

Your issue is at

> comment,
>   :post_id => @post.id) %>

`new_post_comment_path` resolves to `/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new` which doesn't work since its a GET path and doesn't have a POST.
You have to post to `/:post_id/comments(.:format)`

Since I can try it out locally now you could try

```
<%= link_to "Reply", post_comment_path(:parent_id => comment, :post_id => @post.id), method: :post %>
```

or manually add the correct path like

```
link_to 'foo', :action => :foo, :id => @bar.id, method: :post
```

or

```
link_to 'foo', '/foo/#{@bar.id}', method: :post
```

Comment: <%= link_to "Reply", post_comment_path(:parent_id => comment, :post_id => @post.id) %> , it directed to comment show path which i dont have a show comment path sir

Comment: did some edit. possible that you have to set the method to POST.